# bash - extracting lines that contain only 3 columns

Tags: bash, sorting, pipeline, pipelining

I have a file that include the following lines :

> 2 | blah | blah 
>   1 | blah | blah 
>   3 | blah 
>   2 | blah | blah 
>   1 
>   1 | high | five 
>   3 | five

I wanna extract only the lines that has 3 columns (3 fields, 2 seperators...) 
I wanna pipe it to the following commands :

> | sort -nbsk1 | cut -d "|" -f1 | uniq -d

So after all I will get only :

> 2 
>   1

Any suggestions ? 
It's a part of homework assignment, we are not allowed to use awk\sed and some more commands.. (grep\tr and whats written above can be used)

Thanks

Comment: If it's a homework, what did you try?

Comment: I tried checking it line by line instead of sorting it.
Much less "friendly" then checking a sorted and a ready list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep '.*|.*|.*'` will select lines with **at least** three fields and two separators.

Comment: but not `extract only the lines that has 3 columns` e.g. `a|b|c|d` will be matched too. it does it in greedy way.

Comment: yeah @Kent, I will try to improve it.

Comment: We know for sure (we can assume it) that we'll have a maximum of 3 columns, so cannot have this situation.

Comment: @NadavPeled please write those stuff in your question next time. it is very important information.

Comment: @NadavPeled if so, I think my solution is what you need.

Comment: Can it be piped before the sort so the sort will get only the lines with 3 columns ?

Comment: @NadavPeled yeah, try it yourself.

Comment: Sorry for the bump, but we wrote it, it worked, and suddenly stopped working. Is this pipe correct ?

done < $1 | `echo grep '.*|.*|.*'` | sort -nbsk1 | cut -d "|" -f1 | uniq -d

Answer (score 1):

since you said grep is allowed:

```
grep -E '^([^|]*\|){2}[^|]*$' file
```

Comment: @tarrsalah thx. for OP's requirement, I think `grep '|.*|' ` works too.